# Search FirstName and LastName Using Like Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When trying to search with the random words I'm not getting the actual output as expected in some scenarios. Kindly help me solving the same.

Thanks in advance!!

```
declare @FirstName varchar(100) = 'Tim cook'
declare @LastName varchar(100) = 'Apple'
Select @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName AS UserName
where @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName  LIKE '%Tim%'
```

> Output - Tim cook Apple

```
declare @FirstName varchar(100) = 'Tim cook'
declare @LastName varchar(100) = 'Apple'
Select @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName AS UserName
where @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName  LIKE '%cook Apple%'
```

> Output - Tim cook Apple

```
declare @FirstName varchar(100) = 'Tim cook'
declare @LastName varchar(100) = 'Apple'
Select @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName AS UserName
where @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName  LIKE '%Tim Apple%'
```

> Output - Empty

Expected Output - Tim cook Apple

Here there will be a space used as a separator between Tim and cook.

Is there any possibilities, that when I take the first word in the FirstName and the LastName for searching
so that my return value is the same as the previous output's...?

Comment: Try `LIKE '%Tim% %Apple%'` in your third query...

Comment: @deHaar You should post this as an answer

Comment: @AndyHames good advice ;-)

Comment: Use full text search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a wildcard between the two words:

```
where @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName  LIKE '%Tim%Apple%'
```

If you need word-based searching, though, you should look into a full text index.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for the names `Tim` and `Apple` with (or without) anything in between plus a single whitespace, you can do it like this:

```sql
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(100) = 'Tim cook'
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(100) = 'Apple'

SELECT
    @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName AS UserName
WHERE
    @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName  LIKE '%Tim% %Apple%' -- IMPROVEMENT HERE
```

Otherwise `%Tim%%Apple%` or the answer given by @GordonLinoff will do.

Answer (score -1):

There is a notable difference when using VARCHAR/NVARCHAR and CHAR/NCHAR datatype.
Concatening CHAR/NCHAR will not remove spaces while using VARCHAR/NVARCHAR does not usually containes spaces characters.
So the best way to do as you want is to write your where clause like :

```
where TRIM(@FirstName) + ' ' + TRIM(@LastName)  LIKE '%cook Apple%'
```

Comment: As the query doesn't use `CHAR/NCHAR` anywhere and there is no issue with whitespace it's unclear how this is an answer. It should probably be a comment instead.

Comment: This does not address that the OP wants to search for `Tim` and `Apple` and not `cook`